# Failing Archive App RestKit 0.10

Tags: ios, restkit

I have been using RestKit 0.10.2 in my iOS 6.0 project for a while. I have been making Ad Hoc provisioned Archives for testing on other devices without issue. After the recent updates I now have iOS SDK 6.1.

I am still able to run my app on the iPhone simulator, and on a phone (which still has iOS 6.0), but I am not able to build for archive anymore. It now comes up with the following errors:

```
"_lcl_configure_by_name", referenced from:
  -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKClient", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  objc-class-ref in [MY_CLASS]ViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in [MY_CLASS]ViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in [MY_CLASS].o
  objc-class-ref in [MY_CLASS]ViewController.o
"_RKLogInitialize", referenced from:
  -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

There are also similar errors appearing for the RestKit classes: `RKParams`, `RKParserRegistry`, `RKMIMETypeJSON`, `RKRequestSerialization`, `RKObjectMapping`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the armv7s from the architecture build settings. This is not necessary for anything other than high performance games on the iPhone 5 processor. Likely the restkit project build settings are not building armv7s binaries. The easiest thing is to eliminate the armv7s from your main project so it doesn't try to link that.

Comment: Thank you for this. I've not tested the archive yet but it built without errors!