# Error When Running on iPhone, Works fine on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I get this error when I try to run on a device. When I run it on a simulator it works fine.

This is the error I get:

```
Ld "/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Munch_Box-ebibgicdmigfwdbgfdcshfqvxxrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Munch Box.app/Munch Box" normal armv7s
    cd "/Users/xxx/Projects/xCode Projects/Munch Box"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -L/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Munch_Box-ebibgicdmigfwdbgfdcshfqvxxrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Munch_Box-ebibgicdmigfwdbgfdcshfqvxxrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist "/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Munch_Box-ebibgicdmigfwdbgfdcshfqvxxrc/Build/Intermediates/Munch Box.build/Debug-iphoneos/Munch Box.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/Munch Box.LinkFileList" -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -stdlib=libc++ -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Munch_Box-ebibgicdmigfwdbgfdcshfqvxxrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libqrencoder.a -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o "/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Munch_Box-ebibgicdmigfwdbgfdcshfqvxxrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Munch Box.app/Munch Box"

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Munch_Box-ebibgicdmigfwdbgfdcshfqvxxrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libqrencoder.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Munch_Box-ebibgicdmigfwdbgfdcshfqvxxrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libqrencoder.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QREncoder", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TodaysCodeViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7?

Comment: Yeah I tried that, all my libraries are add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off the armv7s in the build settings architectures area. See my answer at [Failing Archive App RestKit 0.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900017/failing-archive-app-restkit-0-10/14901073#14901073)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete Derived Data, clean and restart xCode.
You can delete derived data in organizer (cmd+shift+2 or window->organizer) on the projects tab select yours project and press delete on derived data, then clean.

It may helps, but not sure